# Get string with separator

Tags: shell

I am trying to get a string from a .txt file with this separator `;` and this command:

```
grep -i "${tableIn}" "${READ_FILE}" | cut -d ';' -f1
```

for example: the .txt file contains this line

```
hello;goodbye;see
```

but when looking for the string 'o' the result is 'hello' completely. How can I get the specific string?

Comment: Which shell is this? It might be relevant.

Comment: Add the `-o` parameter to your `grep`.

Comment: What are the values of your variables? Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do? It sounds like you just want `grep -o 'o' file.txt` at the moment.

Comment: I need to search a specify string in a .txt file separated with ; to then compare it with another string entered by a user.

Comment: Both `hello` and `goodbye` contain `'o'` - do you always want to take the first and ignore remaining matches?

Comment: as the separator is ; the command take hello; and not goodbye; because the primary string finish with o;

Answer (score 0):

When `table_in.txt` is your file with all searchstrings and `read.txt` the file where you want to match with the first fields, try

```
cut -d ";" -f1 read.txt > read.tmp.txt
grep -of table_in.txt read.tmp.txt
```

The temp file is not needed with process substitution:

```
grep -of table_in.txt <(cut -d ";" -f1 read.txt)
```